# Where to start on a tile view

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml, windows-store-apps

I would like an exact copy of the windows 8 startpage (or windows phone if you like) as a control in my WinRT application..

Like this one in silverlight [telerik](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#TileView/FirstLook) but than for WinRT

Must be clickable (the easy part) and dragable (the hardest part)

I've been searching for examples but couldn't find any good.. does anybody has a good starting point or tip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try [Telerik HubTile](http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-8/controls/hubtile.aspx).

Telerik offers different types of tile type

## Windows 8 Style Tiles

[image: Windows 8 Style Tiles]

## Rotating and Sliding Tiles

[image: Rotate or Slide Any Content]

## Other Tile Types

[image: Other Tiles]

Comment: @Flores put them in `GridView` as items and then you can drag them.